# removing a coworkers remote branch

Tags: git

I have a coworker that checked in several branches into origin.  He cleaned them up recently, but when I do a git branch -r I see all the old remote branches still.  They are no longer listed in GitHub.  How do I clear my local git db of these branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git remote prune origin` will get rid of them.